# Exclude class member by specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clang++

I have base class template, on that I'm making some another class, which are specialized versions of my base class. I know how to exclude some methods from particular specialization case, but is there any possibility to make that for class's members? Example code, of what I want to achieve:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
  This variable exists only when T==integer VARIABLE;
}

template <Typename T>
WithVariable = using Base<int>;

template <Typename T>
Without = using Base<double>
```

I think that I should use std::enable in some way, but using it makes possible to make VARIABLE of type "void", when I don't want that variable. That is still not the situation I want to achieve.

Comment: You don't need `std::enable_if` just specialization of templated parent class of `Base`. PS. you cannot create variable of type `void`...

Comment: Please be more concrete.

Comment: I would like to pass as one of template parametrs, bool value. Bool value will be indicate if for example animal has trunk, and if yes I want to have member len_of_trunk in class animal_with_trunk. animal_with_trunk has to be specialized version of base class animal. I can't use inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just specialise the class without the unwanted members?

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
  T t;
};

template <>
class Base<int> {
};

int main() {
  Base<int> foo;
  foo.t = 42; // Error: no member named 't' in 'Base<int>'
}
```

Comment: But there is a problem with methods than. And if I want to exclude only one member from many members, than I have to duplicate code. Am I right?

Comment: You're right, this doesn't seem to work with methods, and it's quite possible I don't know what I'm talking about: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aaKLWW5eO3L8H93O

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to do this is to inherit conditionally. Take a look:

```
struct BaseWithVariable {
    int n {42};
};

struct BaseNoVariable {};


template <typename T>
struct Base : std::conditional<std::is_same<T, int>::value, BaseWithVariable, BaseNoVariable>::type {};
```

and usage:

```
Base<int> b {};
Base<double> d {};

std::cout << b.n << std::endl;
std::cout << d.n << std::endl; // error
```

You can also write an explicit specialization for your type, but if you have a group of types (like integers or type derived from specific base) which should have different members than general type, this solution can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a base for base that use SFINAE

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename = void>
struct base_of_base;

template <typename T>
struct base_of_base<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
 { int var; };

template <typename T>
struct base_of_base<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
 { };

template <typename T>
class base : public base_of_base<T>
 { };

int main()
 {
   base<int>     bi;
   base<long>    bl;
   base<float>   bf;
   base<double>  bd;

   bi.var = 1; // OK
   bl.var = 1; // OK
   // bf.var = 1; // error: ‘class base<float>’ has no member named ‘var’
   // bd.var = 1; // error: ‘class base<double>’ has no member named ‘var’
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `delete`ing the functions from specialisations of the class?

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
  void notUseful();
};

template<typename T>
void Base<T>::notUseful(){
  std::cout << "not useful" << std::endl;
  return;
}

template <>
void Base<int>::notUseful() = delete;
```